# Index name not found - When running in embedded mode

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have pre-populated the graph database with some data. When i try to query the database using Junit (via spring service), the query executes fine in embedded mode. The result is returned.

The same query when i try executing via a custom spring endpoint (which access the service method), i get and exception : "Index  does not exist".

This exception is thrown when the cypher query is executed that accesses the index.

> However, one thing to note, when i run the wep app in non embedded mode (via rest api), >the same query executes successfully and result are returned.

Both Junit and web app is pointing to the embedded database running in embedded mode. The embedded database is loaded using JUnit and then accessed via web application (spring endpoint controller=>service->Neo4jTemplate->execute Cypher Query) and Junit (service->Neo4jTemplate->execute Cypher Query).

I'm using:
-    spring data neo4j: 2.2.2.RELEASE and
-    Neo4j GDB 1.9

Not sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed this issue. I had relative path defined. Changing it to absolute path to the embedded graph database, resolved this issue.

Comment: Eg: instead of **"target/xxx"** where xxx is the directory name. I changed it to **"C:/<path to my project>/target/xxx"** when running in a a web application solved this issue. Index not found error is quite misleading.